# Database query to find item not answered by a user previously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to RoR and haven't done any web programming in about 10 years, so please be kind...

I have two tables, questions and responses.  responses belongs_to questions and questions has-many responses.  I'm trying to do a query that will find a random question whose 'open' is true and whose responses do NOT include any by a user with a certain ID.  This is where things stand right now:

```
offset = rand(Question.joins(:responses).where('responses.user_id <> ? and open = ?',     current_user.id, "true").count)
@question = Question.joins(:responses).where('responses.user_id <> ? and open = "true"', current_user.id, "true" ).at(offset)
```

There is a question in my database whose status is open and that has not been answered by the user with ID=1, but these queries are returning nothing.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Break it out and check the parts:

```
What does rand(Question) return ?  
What does rand(Question.joins(:responses) return ?
What does Question.joins(:responses).where(...) return ?
What does Question.where 'responses.user_id <> ? and open = true', current_user.id) return
```

etc.

Do this in the rails console.  If current_user isn't available, find the user you want and set `current_user` equal to id or just use an id number, e.g. '23'

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a model similar to yours, so this is kind of a shot in the dark, buuut...

You don't want to pass the string "true" into your query, because open will never equal the string "true". It's a Boolean, not a string. Presumably.

So try something like this instead:

```
offset = rand(Question.joins(:responses).where('responses.user_id <> ? and open = ?',     current_user.id, true).count)
@question = Question.joins(:responses).where('responses.user_id <> ? and open = ?', current_user.id, true).at(offset)
```

No promises but it's a start.

I actually thought of a much easier way to accomplish this rather than using two separate queries!

Try this:

```
Question.joins(:responses).where('responses.user_id <> ? and open = ?', current_user.id, true).order('RAND()').first
```

This won't work in things like SQLite that don't have a `RAND()` operator, but otherwise it'll give you one random record that meets the rest of the criteria.

Comment: I agree that might the issue.  I have a feeling that rails Active Record deals with it but I would check.  I would also see what value is in the database directly, e.g. mysql prompt or pgadmin 3 data browser, etc.  If it just has a "1" then try that (`open = 1`)

Answer (score 0):

```
Question.joins(:responses).where('user_id <> ? and open = ?', current_user, true).order('RANDOM()').first
```